# Algorithm That Checks Just Part Of Custom Size TicTacToe Game

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, rest, tic-tac-toe

I wrote algortihm tht checks just part of tic tac toe game board, let's say its 10x10 size.
There's no need to iterate throught whole board every time, just around player move index + game diffuculty in each direction.

Here is my impl:

```
 private boolean checkHorizontalWin(String gameBoard, int gameSize, int gameDifficulty, int moveIdx) {
    // CHECK HORIZONTAL WIN
    int moveX = moveIdx / gameSize; // 15/10=1
    int moveY = moveIdx % gameSize; // 15%10=5

    int startX = clamp(moveX - gameDifficulty, 0, gameSize);
    int startY = clamp(moveY - gameDifficulty, 0, gameSize);
    int endX = clamp(moveX + gameDifficulty, 0, gameSize);
    int endY = clamp(moveY + gameDifficulty, 0, gameSize);

    for (int row = startY; row < endY; row++) {
        char candidate = getPawnAtCoords(gameBoard, gameSize, row, 0);
        int counter = 1;
        for (int column = startX; column < endX; column++) {
            char pawn = getPawnAtCoords(gameBoard, gameSize, row, column);

            if ((pawn == candidate) && (pawn != '-')) {
                counter++;
            } else {
                counter = 1;
                candidate = pawn;
            }

            if (counter == gameDifficulty) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
 private int clamp(int val, int min, int max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, val));
}
```

---

```
 private char getPawnAtCoords(String board, int gameSize, int row, int column) {
    int index = row * gameSize + column; // 1 * 10 + 5
    return board.charAt(index);
}
```

Algorithm is not working as it's should when player move index is placed on board corner.
Anyone gat an idea?

Comment: What's your question exacly, an idea for what? If you have errors, please include them in the question

Comment: Sorry, just did

Comment: I find the code quite complex for what it does, it would have been easier to work with arrays rather than a flat list. Can you expand on "not working as it's should", what do you get that inexpected?

Comment: Then I will need to convert GameBoard to arrays just for those menthods, that's unnecessary. I got different bugs in differnet board corners. Sometimes its one player move too fast sometimes I nned to put 4 in row not 3.

Comment: Yes this was just a remark, don't change your data just to fit some methods, but it can be a reminder for future projects, what I meant is that does the method return win when it shouldn't, or does it fail to report a win, or both? You seem to say that it fails to report wins rather?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with `candidate = getPawnAtCoords(gameBoard, gameSize, row, 0)` you read a cell that might not be in the region you want to inspect: the column 0 might not be anywhere near. Yet, you **count** that cell. So for instance, with a 3-in-a-row game, when you scan the first row where a move was made in column 10, then that row might look like this:

```
X------XX-X----
          ^ last move
       ^ inner loop starts here, but count is already 1 before it starts
^ this X is counted erroneously
```

Your initialisation of `candidate` will count the left X and then will find two more X starting at index 7 (i.e. 10 - 3), and conclude there is a 3-in-a-row, but this is a false positive.

You can solve this in many ways. For instance, this will do the trick:

```
char candidate = '-';
int counter = 0;
```

Secondly, your encoding of an index (from row/column) is different from the *decoding* of an index (into row/column). In `getPawnAtCoords` the `column` is the smaller unit, and the `row` the bigger one (it is multiplied), yet in `checkHorizontalWin` you extract `moveX` as the bigger unit (as you divide), which is later used for the loop variable `column`.

You can fix this by changing the initialisation of `moveX` and `moveY` to:

```
    int moveX = moveIdx % gameSize;
    int moveY = moveIdx / gameSize;
```

Finally, this is an overly complex algorithm. You already know what the last move was, as you can read `gameBoard[moveX]` and it is **that** character you want to check with, nothing else. So the variable `candidate` could be set to it -- only once. Then you don't need that `pawn == '-'` check anymore and only need to reset the counter to 0 when you find a character that is different from `candidate`.

Moreover, for horizontal wins it is not necessary to look at any other row than the row of the last move.

Comment: Nice catch, I would add that there are other design flaws, such as the params `board, gameSize, gameDifficulty` passed to each function, while these should be accessible by the functions. Indeed there is nothing else than check right and left of the last move while testing if the border of the board has not been reached